# Tabbar is not showing in extended views in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

! am an objective c beginner. I have researched hours on this issue and have watched youtube videos but still cant solve this problem - I have created tabbar controller with first view as the first tab as dispalyed in the pic. I then tried to extend the first view with two more views: one master table view and one detail UIView. The first view is linked to the master table view through the button on the first view. I compiled to run the project, everything is smooth except the tabbar is not showing on the master table view and detail UIView. I tried to add in the tabbar item, but still nothing is shown. I also checked the attribute inspectors to ensure the bottom bar property is set to "infered", what can i do now? thanks for your help. [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The view controller loaded by the Tab bar controller must be a UINavigationController. Looking at the image that you have uploaded here I don't think that is happening in your case. The following image must help you understand my point.[image]

Once you set up your storyboard like above your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks, if i want the navigation controller to be applied to first view and second view, should i put another naviagation controller before the second view in your image? or i can put the navigation controller before the tab bar controller?

Comment: Yes, you have to put a navigation controller for second view. If you present the tab bar controller within the navigation controller then your tab controller will be removed once a different view controller is pushed (i.e; when the button is clicked).