# Show tab bar on all view controllers of application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8

I have a problem, I have 2 view controllers on the tab bar controllers. Both these controllers are showing tabs. But when I made a push segue from View controller 1 to View controller 3. View controller 3 do not show the tab bar.

I want to show tab on all the controllers of my application. 
[image: my situation]

Comment: Find answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15634597/2439156

Comment: Just shift the position on navigation controller before controller 1. it will work as you are excepting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your Storyboard Design:

- set TabBar View Controller as initial ViewController
- set your UINavigationViewController as root view controller for each Tab
- After all, your Design structure will look like mention Image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should realize your struct of views.

Now, you have a NavigationController first, and its rootViewController is a Tab BarController.

```
NavigationController[0] = TabBarController
```

and your TabBarController has 2 ViewController( Controller 1 and Controller 2 )

```
NavigationController[0] = TabBarController
```

then it includes 2 controllers like

```
TabBarController[0] = Controller 1

TabBarController[1] = Controller 2
```

when you call

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController
```

it means the NavigationController push to Controller 3,
so controller 3 will not show tab bar because it is not in TabBarController.

if you wanna push to controller 3 and still has tab bar,
you can insert a container in Controller 1 ( or insert a View ),
and create a NavigationController like this

```
let nav = NavigationController(rootViewController: yourController1)
self.yourViewInsertedInController1.addSubview(nav.view)
```

then in yourController1 run

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController
```

it will be right.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem exist because your `UITabViewController` is embedded in the navigation stack that you initialize as a initial controller.

You must re-build things so that your tab bar controller tabs opens to a new navigation stack.

- Remove the first `UINavigationController` , you don't need it ( if you want it don't use a push segue, use a modal segue, and you won't then be referring back to that `UINavigationController`'s viewController stack from
  inside your `UITabViewController`
- Embed each of the first `UIViewControllers` in your
  `UITabViewController` inside a separate `UINavigationController`.

Now you can push segue within your `UITabViewController's` tabs

Answer (score -1):

To add the view controller to the tab bar controller's array of view controllers, drag from the tab bar controller to that view controller, holding down the Control key. Select Relationship Segue > view controllers from the menu that appears.